# Seeing Z value from Exported Data (NOAA) using QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, noaa, z-value

I open the ENC Direct data (any file) (https://www.charts.noaa.gov/ENCs/ENCs.shtml) in ArcMap using Esri's free S-57 loader extension and I'm able to see the SOUNDG_P layer and can display the Depth.

The data is definitely in there:

[image]

However, when I open the same file in QGIS, I see only points but no Z Value which are not in attributes.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no s-57 loader for QGIS.  [See this link](https://www.sigterritoires.fr/index.php/en/displaying-marine-charts-with-s57-qgis/) for viewing ENCs in QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add A.000 S-57 file to QGIS
2. Find SOUNDG layer in Layer list and observe it (open Attribute table). You will find out, that there are fewer records as points on map display
3. You have to explode multipart to single part feature in order to get all points as single point. You can do that with "Multipart to singleparts" tool in Processing Toolbox
4. Open attribute table of new (permanent or temporary) layer and you will see all the points. Now you have to obtain depth attribute from geometry.
5. Open Field Calculator in opened attribute table of new layer and get the z value of new layer, which is in fact 3D point

[image: Add Z value for Depth]

6. Label the Depth in Layer Properties:

[image: labeling]